# UITextfield : Text jumps up and down while typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am having problem with the textfield input. In the 'CommentviewController' I have a scrollable tableview to display the previous comments, and at the bottom is a UItextField for the user to enter the comment and post it. The problem is: when I tried to type in the textfield and the keyboard is toggled, the text jumps up and down while I 'm typing. For example, the first char I typed is above the keyboard, and the second is below and behind the keyboard. Anybody has any idea about the cause? The test device is a 64 GB itouch5, and the code is written in objective C, and I am using the Xcode 6.3.2.

```
    <i>`- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
 NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo]; 
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size; 
theKBSize = kbSize; 
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height - 10, 0.0); 
self.tvComment.contentInset = contentInsets; self.tvComment.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets; 
CGRect uvFrame = _uvComment.frame; 
uvFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - kbSize.height - _uvComment.frame.size.height; _uvComment.frame = uvFrame; } `</i>

    <i> `- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification { 
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero; 
_tvComment.contentInset = contentInsets;
 _tvComment.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets; 
}`</i>

    <i>`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { 
if(string==nil || [string length]<1) { 
[self.btnSend setEnabled: NO];
 }else {
 [self.btnSend setEnabled: YES]; 
}
 return YES; 
}`</i>
```

Comment: please share the code of your CommentviewController

Comment: without code it is very much difficult to give an solution. Also please note that question should be understandable easily for quick answer.

Comment: - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    theKBSize = kbSize;
    
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height - 10, 0.0);
    self.tvComment.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tvComment.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    
     CGRect uvFrame = _uvComment.frame;
    uvFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - kbSize.height - _uvComment.frame.size.height;
    _uvComment.frame = uvFrame;
}

Comment: // Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _tvComment.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _tvComment.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
  }
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(string==nil || [string length]<1)
    {
        [self.btnSend setEnabled: NO];
    }else
    {
        [self.btnSend setEnabled: YES];
    }
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Here is the code related

Comment: Can you please update your question by putting together all your relevant code so that it makes easier for us to find solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the scroll position of the `tableView`?

A `UITableView` will automatically scroll so that the `UITextField` is not hidden by the keyboard when selected and the keyboard pops up. If you are changing the scroll position, that could be interfering with the auto scroll behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?